# sfdx pre-release slow to install

Tags: salesforcedx

It takes too long to complete install, why?

```
sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release
```

Its been more than one hour, but sfdx is still installing.

[image]

Comment: You may want to try restarting your computer, closing all non-essential startup programs, and trying again. It may or may not help, but that worked for me at least once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, 
my salesforcedx was crashed!
after I use following command, it repaired automatically.
sfdx plugins --core[image: cmd_img]

Comment: Can you accept your own answer?